# Python: Strip everything but spaces and alphanumeric

Tags: python

I have a large string with brackets and commas and such. I want to strip all those characters but keep the spacing. How can I do this. As of now I am using

```
strippedList = re.sub(r'\W+', '', origList)
```

Comment: And why are you not happy with your current solution?

Comment: Ah I just needed to change '' to ' '.
fail
Thanks man

Answer (score 47):

```
re.sub(r'([^\s\w]|_)+', '', origList)
```

Comment: Just as a note, that '|_' will slow down your regex. (Won't matter if the input is small, of course.)

Comment: @Ignacio, what is `|_` doing here?

Comment: @chandresh: Undoing the exclusion in `^\w`.

Comment: I think I come to this answer at least once every week.

Answer (score 10):

A bit faster implementation:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile('([^\s\w]|_)+')
strippedList = pattern.sub('', value)
```

Answer (score 8):

The regular-expression based versions might be faster (especially if you switch to using a compiled expression), but I like this for clarity:

```
"".join([c for c in origList if c in string.letters or c in string.whitespace])
```

It's a bit weird with the `join()` call, but I think that is pretty idiomatic Python for converting a list of characters into a string.

Answer (score 1):

Demonstrating what characters you will get in the result:

```
>>> s = ''.join(chr(i) for i in range(256)) # all possible bytes
>>> re.sub(r'[^\s\w_]+','',s) # What will remain
'\t\n\x0b\x0c\r 0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
```

Docs: [re.sub](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub), [Regex HOWTO: Matching Characters](http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html#matching-characters), [Regex HOWTO: Repeating Things](http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html#repeating-things)