# stripping away code in python using "re.sub"

Tags: python, regex, string, formatting

I read this: 
[Stripping everything but alphanumeric chars from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276764/stripping-everything-but-alphanumeric-chars-from-a-string-in-python)

and this: 
[Python: Strip everything but spaces and alphanumeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779453/python-strip-everything-but-spaces-and-alphanumeric)

Didn't quite understand but I tried a bit on my own code, which now looks like this:

```
import re

decrypt = str(open("crypt.txt"))

crypt = re.sub(r'([^\s\w]|_)+', '', decrypt)

print(crypt)
```

When I run the script It comes back with this answer: 
*C:\Users\Adrian\Desktop\python>python tick.py
**ioTextIOWrapper namecrypttxt moder encodingcp1252***

I am trying to get away all the extra code from the document and just keep numbers and letter, inside the document the following text can be found: http://pastebin.com/Hj3SjhxC

I am trying to solve the assignment here: 
http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/ocr.html

Anyone knows what "ioTextIOWrapper namecrypttxt moder encodingcp1252" means? 
And how should I format the code to properly strip it from everything except letter and numbers?

Sincerely

Comment: you should also tag this with `regex`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just search for the alphanumeric chars instead. Like this:

```
print ''.join(re.findall('[A-Za-z]', decrypt))
```

And you also want:

```
decrypt = open("crypt.txt").read()
```

Comment: where is the "print ''.join(re.findall('[A-Za-z]', decrypt))" part going in my code? 

Thanks for fixing the open file problem I didnt even know I had :)

Comment: Well instead of removing everything except letters, it's much easier just to look for the letters themselves.

Comment: [A-Z] means any letters from A to Z, and same with the a-z except lowercase

Comment: Yea but I mean where should I put it? 
This is what I have done to the code now: 

import re

decrypt = open("crypt.txt").read()



print(''.join(re.findall('[A-Za-z]', decrypt)

It results in the following error: 
C:\Users\Adrian\Desktop\python>python tick.py
  File "tick.py", line 12

    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: Looks like you forgot a `)` at the end

Comment: Yes! There it was! Thank you soooo much! :)

Comment: No Problem! :) 
Btw, if you ever need more help on regular expressions check out the Python docs [page](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) on it

Answer (score 5):

`str(open("file.txt"))` doesn't do what you think it does.  `open()` returns a file object.  `str` gives you the string representation of that file object, *not* the contents of the file.  If you want to read the contents of the file use `open("file.txt").read()`.

Or, more safely, use a `with` statement:

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    decrypt = f.read()
crypt = ... 
# etc.
```