# Counting the number of occurrences of a word in a text file

Tags: python, word-count

I want to count the number of times each word is found in the text file and am not sure what is wrong. When I run it I get the count as 0. I was also having trouble finding a way to include in the count the occurrences where the word is capitalized as well (count both dog and Dog occurrences)

```
def main():
text_file = open("textfile.txt", "r")

dog_count = 0
cat_count = 0

for word in text_file.readlines():
    if word == 'dog':
        dog_count= dog_count + 1
    else:
        dog_count= dog_count

print('the word dog occurs',dog_count,'times')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficiently count word frequencies in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35857519/efficiently-count-word-frequencies-in-python)

Comment: your iterating over lines instead of words.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that you are looping of the lines of the file and not the words.  You need to add in another loop to go through each word.

**Warning**: the example below is un-tested but should be close enough.

```
def main():
    text_file = open("textfile.txt", "r")

    dog_count = 0
    cat_count = 0

    for line in text_file.readlines():
        for word in line.split():
            if word == 'dog':
                dog_count= dog_count + 1

    print('the word dog occurs',dog_count,'times')
```

Comment: You are correct, it will not do that.  I would point you to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779453/python-strip-everything-but-spaces-and-alphanumeric for examples of stripping out the punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the text into upper/lower cases during your search:

def main():
    text_file = open("textfile.txt", "r")

```
dog_count = 0
cat_count = 0

for line in text_file.readlines():
    for word in line.split():
        word = word.lower() #case convertion
        if word == 'dog':
            dog_count= dog_count + 1

print "The word dog occurs",dog_count,"times"
```

main()

It should work fine, tested and working fine for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:** With respect the question of 'why wrong output' - You need to iterate through every word in your line.

**Suggestion:**
When you are search for multiple words, you can have them in a dict and store the count as the value of the corresponding dict key.

Content of file:

```
Hi this is hello
Hello is my name
```

Then

```
text_file.read()
```

will give,

```
['Hi this is hello\n', 'Hello is my name\n']

text_file.read().splitlines()
['Hi this is hello', 'Hello is my name']
```

Then split every line in your lines,

```
lines = map(str.split,text_file.read().splitlines())
[['Hi', 'this', 'is', 'hello'], ['Hello', 'is', 'my', 'name']]
```

On chaining the iterable,

```
it.chain.from_iterable(map(str.split,text_file.read().splitlines()))
['Hi', 'this', 'is', 'hello', 'Hello', 'is', 'my', 'name']
```

And,

```
search=['dog','cat'] # the words that you need count
search = dict.fromkeys(search,0) # will give a dict as {'dog':0,'cat':0}
```

Therefore for your problem,

```
def main():
        text_file =  open("textfile.txt", "r")
        search=['cat','dog']
        search = dict.fromkeys(search,0)
        import itertools as it
        res=dict()
        for word in it.chain.from_iterable(map(str.split,text_file.read().splitlines())):
                if word.lower() in search:
                        search[word.lower()]=search[word.lower()]+1
        for word,count in search.iteritems():
                print('the word %s occurs %d times'%(word,count))
```

This get the count of case sensitive words too!

Hope it helps!