# Remove all special characters from text except for "\n" and "/"

Tags: python, nlp

From this post I found how to remove everything from a text than spaces and alphanumeric: [Python: Strip everything but spaces and alphanumeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779453/python-strip-everything-but-spaces-and-alphanumeric).

In this way:

```
re.sub(r'([^\s\w]|_)+', '', document)
```

I wanted basically to remove all the special characters.

However, now I want to do the same (i.e. to remove all the special characters) but without removing the following special characters:

1. \n
2. /

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try rewriting your pattern without using the rigid character classes:

```
document = "Hello!@#$/ World!"
output = re.sub(r'[^ \nA-Za-z0-9/]+', '', document)
print(output)

Hello/ World
```

This says to remove any character which is not alphanumeric, space, newline, or forward slash.

Comment: The question is: Should `'Motörhead'` be an alphanumeric string or not?

Comment: @Matthias What about `Radiöhead`?  Never liked their music anyway though.

Comment: Thanks, this looks good. By the way, I do not if your comments are related to this but I am wondering if letters such as `ö` are considered special characters and hence they will be removed? If yes then this is a problem - I may write or find a separate question for this.

Comment: @PoeteMaudit Yes, accented characters would be removed, but you could also include them in the character class.  The problem here, as you have seen, is that saying `[^\w]` would automatically exclude `/`.

Comment: Ok yes so probably I will have to write or find a separate question about this since I want to keep all accented letters.

Answer (score 1):

I may be missing the full use case but you could do this without `regex`:

```
s = "test\r\n\\ this\n"
s = ''.join(char for char in s if char.isalnum() or char in {'\\', '\n', ' '})
print(s)
```

The `.isalnum()` handles most alpha numeric characters including unicode.